# Twilio Conference Moderating

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, servicenow, twilio-twiml, conference

We are implementing ServiceNow + Twilio and finding it rather difficult to accomplish what I think should be a basic thing.  With AT&T conference calls, users are able to *6 to mute/unmute themselves.  We are also able to see who is talking via their conference monitor in order to manage disturbances along with disabling entry/exit beeps.

We have been unable to come up with a solution on how to implement these 3 features...

Very stumped =/

Any assistance with this would be GREATLY appreciated friends.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to post a small working example of these things occuring so that someone can try to reproduce and figure out the issue.

Comment: I'm a developer evangelist for Twilio and would love to help, but, as Jace says, it would be really useful to see an example of what you have so far. I also haven't worked with ServiceNow and our APIs, so not sure what you're doing so far. Can you share your code so far?